# Geodesics as analogues to straight lines

Tags: differential-geometry

I was thinking about how the idea of geodesics were presented in Tristan Needham's Visual Differential Geometry as a generalization of how we view straight lines in the Euclidean plane on surfaces.

Now, after thinking a bit more, how the line actually looks like on the surface depends on what metric you choose. So, why is it said in the book that shortest distance between two points can always be given by the [sticky tape construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329396/on-finding-geodesics-of-an-arbitrary-surface/4329413?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C22.8014#4329413)?

---

Quote:

> To construct a geodesic on a surface, emanating from a point p in direction of vector v, stick
> one end of a length of narrow sticky tape down at p and unroll it onto the surface,
> starting in the direction v.
> Pg-13

Comment: Can you provide details of the sticky tape construction from the book, and not the downvoted post that you link to?

Comment: You can check page 13,14 of the book for the detailed explanation

Comment: "how the line actually looks like on the surface depends on what metric you choose" . When he says surface I'm guessing he's referring to an actual surface (embedded in 3D space), not a purely abstract surface. Such would be a football, or a piece of lettuce.  A surface embedded in Euclidean space already comes with a metric (called the "induced metric") . The idea of an induced metric is that, since you can measure distances in your ambient (euclidean) space, and your surface lives in that space, you can measure distances along your surface. Theretofore, induced metric.

Comment: A good intuition for how  the tape method works  is to imagine the surface as being made of lots of tiny (but straight) triangles. 

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wai-Lam-4/publication/279309601/figure/fig2/AS:667599796989961@1536179603722/Left-A-triangulated-surface-n-V-S-2-with-vertices-on-the-unit-sphere-Right-A.png

Then on the "unfolded" surface the tape will give you straight lines.
https://d2r55xnwy6nx47.cloudfront.net/uploads/2021/01/Figure-January-Academy_17.svg

Comment: At best, the sticky tape construction is meant to give an intuition for geodesics as straight lines on a surface relative to the geometry of the surface inherited from the ambient $\Bbb{R}^n$ (I answered what this means precisely in one of your previous questions). But yes in a general Riemannian manifold, there is no more sticky tape analogy because without you giving a proper definition, things like "straightness" or "unrolling sticky tape" or any other such vague terms are just that: vague terms. So, we need to give precise definitions and show they reduce to the appropriate special case.

Comment: Does keeping the object in 3D space immediately fix how we think of distances on it? That seems a bit weird..

Comment: If it's a surface, yes. An ant walking between 2 points on a paper will have to walk the same distance regardless of how you bend or fold the paper. On the other hand, if it's something fluid like the surface of wax or water (or a rubber balloon that deflates or inflates), then its distances are not fixed. But that's only because the object itself is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

In developable surfaces:

In Cones and Tangent developable surface helicoidal geodesic tapes become straight tapes on development. The analogy is striking.

In non-developable surfaces:

When applying a sticky tape ( or a sufficiently wide tape/strip ) on a surface, one should be careful that no bending to left or right occurs, so no sidewise wrinkles on one side should be seen when geodesic path is laid guided by fingers. I.e., no geodesic curvature in the tangent plane.

The method is employed to trace geodesics on doubly curved surfaces starting from a given single point and a given starting direction.

In the special case using cylindrical coordinates on a surface of revolution  the **same symbolic differential equation** holds  for the surface **and** also for a developed cone, known as the Clairaut's Law. ( $\psi$ is angle of tape to meridian and $r$ the radius at any point. )

$$    r \sin \psi = r_{min}$$

For cones and tangential developable the tape is tangential to a minimum circle and thereafter radius increases. In the full plane case the straight line tape can be represented by the polar form of a straight line.